# Anchor-tag in Bootstrap form-group doesn't work with Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

There is an input tag on the same line with an anchor within a div. The anchor tag is completely not reacting in it's position. Yet it works if put on a new line below or above the input field.

```
<div data-states-for="email" class="form-group ">
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" value="someEmailAddress" required="" autocomplete="email" readonly="">
<span style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -25px; z-index: 2;">
    <a href="https://someLink.com" class="fas fa-pencil-alt" onclick="someEventhandler" data-error="account_selection_required">
    </a>
</span>
```

This issue only happens on **Firefox**. Does anybody have any hint towards what's causing it? I'm using **Bootstrap 4.0.0**

Comment: you should use the `input-group` class. [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/) is some documentation.

Comment: Yes, this solved the issue! Thank you a lot!